# Java - Searchable JComboBox - key typing selection and viewable drop down list

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I need to create an editable JComboBox where the possible choices are filtered out of an initial list on the base of the character typed in the box from the user. I was able to find a solution on StackOverflow but I have still two problems:

1. When I enter a key it got displayed as selected, so the next key pressed, instead of being added to the present text it substitute
   the text. I want that the user is able to type in like it was a JTextField.
2. I would like that the first 5 (n?) possible matching values are shown while typing.

I've tried to read online and in specification but I cannot find a solution.

```
JTextComponent editor = (JTextComponent) myComboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
myComboBox.setSelectedItem("");
editor.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
     String[] myValues = Utils.myValues(..get a list o value somehow ...);

     String searchText = (String) myComboBox.getEditor().getItem();

     List<String> filterArrayString = new ArrayList<>();
     for (int i = 0; i < myValues.length; i++) {
       if (myValues[i].toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())) {
           filterArrayString.add(myValues[i]);
       }
     }
    myComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(filterArrayString.toArray()));
    myComboBox.getEditor().setItem(searchText);
   }
});
```

Filter when a letter is pressed, letter is selected

[Filter when a letter is typed, it got selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOdWe.png)

Comment: When the soluton you found is not suitable for you, google for "jcombobox typeahead" and try to use some of found results.

Comment: Use a DocumentListener, not a KeyListener.  You don’t need to update your filtering when the user presses an arrow key.